# How to open a geodatabase stored on a local server using ArcGIS runtime version 100?

Tags: arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf

I want to open a geodatabase stored on a local server.  I need to open this geodatabase so I can use its feature tables but I have not been able to find how to do it?

I am using c# .net and arcgisruntime v 100 , I have 3D cone graphics displayed on my scene, and I have an SQL server geodatabase called "Test".

Connection is established via arcCatalog, so I have an .sde file that stores my connection to my geodatabase localised on our local server.

I wanted to open this geodatabase in order to load its feature table so I can add features on to it. I used the following code:

```
code private async void addFeature(MapPoint structureLocation , string type , string cause) { var gdb = await Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Data.Geodatabase.OpenAsync(@"C:\Users\Manel\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.2\ArcCatalog\Connection to frparsynoserver.sde"); var table = gdb.GeodatabaseFeatureTables.FirstOrDefault(t => t.TableName == "Test"); await table.LoadAsync(); if (table.LoadStatus == Esri.ArcGISRuntime.LoadStatus.Loaded) {
        //  var lyr = new FeatureLayer(table);
        //  MySceneView.Scene.OperationalLayers.Add(lyr);


        var attributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        attributes.Add("typdamage", type);
        attributes.Add("primcause", cause);

        //create a new feature
        var newFeature = table.CreateFeature(attributes, structureLocation);
        await table.AddFeatureAsync(newFeature);

    }


}
```

But it didn't work?

How to open a geodtabase using .sde file connection with arcgisruntime version 100?

Can any one tell me how to do that?

Comment: Hi Manel, welcome to the forum. You may like to put a little more attention to your question in order to get the correct result. Use styling, interpunction and make sure you explain what you already did but didn't work and be specific on what kind of software and database you use. In other words: elaborate!